# What is wrong with my function call?

Tags: c

I am getting a segmentation fault at the function call point. please help with any information. I am new to coding so help with anything else you see would be so greatly appreciated! The segmentation fault happens in the 'main' function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

void write();
void read();

int main()
{
    int x;

    while(x!=2)
    {
        printf("Type 0 to go to write program, type 1 to go to read program, type 2 to end program\n");
        scanf("%d",x);
        if(x==0)
            write();
        if(x==1)
            read();
    }
    return 0;
}

void write()
{
    FILE *finalptr;
    char name[MAX],gift[MAX];
    int none;

    if((finalptr=fopen("names.dat","w"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened\n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Enter the gifter's name2gift.\n");
        printf("Enter EOF to end input.\n");
        printf("? ");
        scanf("%s%d%s",name,none,gift);

        while(!feof(stdin))
        {
            fprintf(finalptr,"%s %s\n",name,gift);
            printf("? ");
            scanf("%s%d%s",name,none,gift);
        }
        fclose(finalptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general advice, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Further general advice: don't use function names like `read()` and `write()` which are part of the standard library. Also turn on compiler warnings and pay attention to the resulting warnings - the compiler will help you fix a lot of your bugs if you let it.

Comment: the function names 'write' and 'read' are standard names defined in stdio.h, so (were it me) I would use some unique names like 'myWrite' and 'myRead'.

Comment: these two lines: void write();
void read();  should be: void write( void ); and void read(void);  And note my comment about the function names conflicting with the names in stdio.h

Comment: when scanf has this format string: 'scanf("%s%d%s",name,none,gift);' Then scanf cannot determine where one field ends and the next begins.  and the line should be written more like this: if( 3 == scanf(" %s %d %s",name,&none,gift); 1) always test the returned value from input functions to assure operations successful, 2) leading ' ' will cause leading white space (including prior newline) to be skipped 3) the user input should/must contain some kind of delimiters.  4) array names degrade to the address of the array, but the int parameter needs the address specified

Comment: this line: printf("Enter EOF to end input.\n"); seems to tell the user to enter the three characters: 'EOF' when what it should be saying is to enter <ctrl-z>  however, it would be much better to not use feof() but just control the loop with the scanf()

Comment: suggest elimination of the int none variable and all references and request user to just enter the username, a space, the gift name, with no spaces in either parameter.

Comment: regarding this line: 'printf("File could not be opened\n");'  it is far better to use perror() rather than printf() because then the reason for the failure will also be output

Comment: @user3629249: The white space skipping of `scanf` doesn't become as you describe it by repeating wrong facts over and over again. Please stop that.

Comment: Regardless of what you see above, *neither* `read()` nor `write()` are part of the *language* standard library; they're part of separate library standards (ex: SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001). Still doesn't mean its a good idea to use those names, but they're *not* part of the [C standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

Comment: First Must be initialize x value.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d",&x);
```

Read to the address of the variable. Which is `&x` not x.
Since you have `%d` as your first arguement of your scanf() the second paramter should be some valid memory location(`int *`) to which the value should be read and in your case since `x` is uninitialized or `x` is not pointing to any valid memory location this will cause segmentation fault.

Fix all your `scanf()'s`

PS: Using uninitialized values will lead to UB( The value `x` is not initialized and it is being used )

Comment: The second argument passed to `scanf` is indeed the problem, but your description is **extremely inaccurate**. Function `scanf` takes `"%d"` as the first argument, and therefore expects the address of an `int` variable as the second argument. OP is passing the (uninitialized) value of `x`, which `scanf` "interprets" as a valid memory address and attempts to write into it during runtime. The result is generally undefined behavior because we don't know what the value of `x` is, but since this value is most likely **not** a valid memory address, the result would be a memory access violation.

Comment: @barakmanos Agree !! Updated my answer with greater detail now

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%d",x);
```

`scanf` `d` conversion specifier requires an argument of type `int *` but you are passing an `int`. Change this call to `scanf("%d", &x);`

You have the same issue in you other `scanf` calls.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
int x;//Error here beacause you have to initialize x
//Though you may not get any errors chances of wrong output
while(x!=2)
 {
    printf("Type 0 to go to write program, type 1 to go to read program, type 2 to end program\n");
    scanf("%d",x);//scanf("%d",&x);
    if(x==0)
        write();
    if(x==1)
        read();
 }
return 0;
}
```

this works.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `x` as integer so in `scanf` you have to put `&`: `scanf("%d",&x);`